# Entity Framework не создает всю базу данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, codefirst

Возникла какая-то непонятная проблема. работал с проектом в visual studio (база создавать через code first entity framework), дропал несколько раз базу, потом опять создавал и все было ок. в один момент дропнул базу и после это студия не хочет создавать ее опять(база создается, но содержит только одну таблицу __EFMigrationsHistory). Никаких ошибок при этом нет. Может у кого-то что-то такое было? не пойму в чем проблема.

При этом что код при создании миграции генерируется:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("DAL.Entities.User", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("ID_user")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<string>("Email")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("ID_Role")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Password")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("ID_user");

                    b.HasIndex("ID_Role");

                    b.ToTable("Users");
                });
```

Логи

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.3 initialized 'ApplicationContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (14ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (15ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
      FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
      ORDER BY [MigrationId];
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20200528174706_1'.
Applying migration '20200528174706_1'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
      VALUES (N'20200528174706_1', N'3.1.3');
Done.
```

Comment: Как можно `создает только таблицу __EFMigrationsHistory` без создания БД?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Как именно вы  создаете БД? Каким кодом вы накатываете существующие миграции? Что в логах EF? Если вы добавляете новую миграцию, она накатывается? в таблице `__EFMigrationsHistory` есть какие то записи?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я код вообще неминял, раньше у меня создавало все нормально, а сейчас не хочет и я не понимаю с чем это может быть связано. Я свой проект сбросил преподавателю, у него нормально создало все таблички, а у меня нет.

Comment: Ваш комментарий не отвечает ни на один из вопросов, что я задал.

Comment: Add-migration first, 
Update-Database.

Comment: что пишет эта команда в ответ?

Comment: `Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.3 initialized 'ApplicationContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.` - Add-migration

Comment: Никаких ошибок нет, в логах информация о создании таблицы __EFMigrationsHistory

Comment: добавьте весь вывод команды в вопрос

Comment: `в логах информация о создании таблицы __EFMigrationsHistory` а информация о создании БД? 4

Comment: После n-ной попытки создать базу со всеми таблицами, оно заработало, код я неминял в принципе. Благодарю за помощь.